# Why is the scenario for (2,3) not returning false but instead returning true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Been trying to understand why when I pass 2, 3 to this function it returns true instead of false.

```js
function solveThis(i, j) {
  if (i || j === 1) {
    return true
  } else if (i + j === 1) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}


console.log(solveThis(2, 3))
```

Comment: `i || j ===1` is equivalent to `i || (j === 1)`. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: `if (2 || 3 === 1)`: 2 is truthy, so returns true.

Comment: See [JavaScript Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence)

Comment: To put it another way, the OR operator evaluates statements, not portions of statements.

Answer (score 1):

A conditional like:

```
if (i || j === 1)
```

means:

> IF:
>
> `i` exists (and is not a *falsy* value like `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, `false` etc.)
>
> OR IF:
>
> `j` is identical to `1`.

You might try:

```
if ((i === 1) || (j === 1))
```